# how can I display time using ApexCharts?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, time, vue-component, apexcharts

I know the ApexCharts can help to display data using timeline chart.
but the example(vue) only shown how to display the date like

````
new Date(1797, 2, 4).getTime(),
new Date(1801, 2, 4).getTime() ```

how can I change the value to display time? like 08:00-09:00
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own x-axis labels in the dataset using the chart's `xaxis` `categories` option.

For example:

```js
options: {
  chart: {
    id: 'mychart'
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['8:00','9:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','1:00','2:00','3:00']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the UTC flag as false in options

```
xaxis:{
 type:"datetime",
 labels:{
 dateTimeUTC:false
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `formatter` on the axis: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/. It isn't exactly the format you asked for, but will set you in the right direction. There are getMinutes() getSeconds() and GetHours() among other functions that can be used to then construct a format you want.

```
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      formatter: function (val: number) {
        return new Date(val).toLocaleTimeString()
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try new Date().getHour to get the hours. And if you want the apexChart X axis to show hours add to the xaxis section this:

`format: 'HH:mm'`